# how to find the lines by ignoring word sequence, in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep, find

I am trying to ignore the order of the words and searching for the line in one file which has below pattern for example :
My Name is ABC.

Now I want to change the sequence of words in the same sentence as below :
ABC is my name.

Can someone  please help me on how should I find this line in linux, if the order/sequence of the words keeps changing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to extract the name?  or just print the whole like if it matches either of the patterns?

Comment: You want to find all lines which include all four words in any order? A trivial attempt for this would be to pipe through several `grep`s like this: `grep -i ABC infile | grep -i my | grep -i is | grep -i name` (The option `-i` to ignore a change in case when words are at the beginning of the sentence).

Comment: @Philippos you probably ought to include `-w` on those so that words containing these as substrings aren't matched, such as `sister`